# run crontab on docker container

Tags: docker, cron, containers

i try to execute a cron directly on the container but its nit working i did :

`

```
apt-get update && apt-get install cron -y 


# Giving executable permission to the script file
RUN chmod +x date-script.sh

mkdir my-cron-file

# Adding crontab to the appropriate location
crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Giving permission to crontab file
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Running crontab
crontab /etc/cron.d/my-cron-file

# Creating entry point for cron 
ENTRYPOINT ["cron", "-f"]
```

`

from [airplane](https://www.airplane.dev/blog/docker-cron-jobs-how-to-run-cron-inside-containers)

but its not working,

do you have an idea ?

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what does happen?  The Dockerfile you've included here isn't syntactically correct; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: i don't use docker file, i want just install on my ubuntu container cron for execut a python script